# ORA-01455: converting column overflow integer datatype

Tags: c++, c, oracle11g, proc

I am getting ORA-01455: converting column overflow integer datatype error in my Proc program. while checking the log it was getting the error from this below line of code.

```
  LineNbr = __LINE__;
  EXEC SQL FOR :lArraySize
           FETCH crs3
           INTO :dbreckriviOut:dbindkriviOut;
```

Particularly for one of the filed value. If the field value <= 2147483647 it works . But if it is >2147483647 then it was giving this error.

Comment: `2147483647` is the largest 32-bit signed integer – can you use a bigger data type?

Comment: The particular field it was defined as long type . Now i changed to long long type and unsigned long also. But it was giving same error.

Comment: Hi,

Does any one knows the problem how to solve that.

If i give unsigned long the result changed as singed value . (before the value added minus symbol)

Comment: With `long long`?

Comment: With long long getting same error like 'ORA-01455: converting column overflow integer datatype'